# File Upload fails, but jqXHR returning status 200 in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, jquery-file-upload

I am using the [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin to call a web service and upload an image to the server.

The image uploads fine, and I've added some validation to the web service that throws an exception if the image is larger than 4MB.

Here is how I am using File Upload plugin:

```
var fileUploadInput = $('#uploader').fileupload({

    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        mainObject._addFile(e, data, mainObject);
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        mainObject._fileUploadDone(e, data, mainObject);
    },
    fail: function (e, data) {
        mainObject._fileUploadFail(e, data, mainObject)
    }
});
```

Now, when the file upload fails, the parameter `data` contains a `jqXHR` object as follows:

```
readyState: 4
status: 200
statusText: "success"
```

In Chrome, the jqXHR contains a lovely error message generated by the exception thrown by the web service. In Fiddler, I can see the response is 400 Bad Response, and I can see the error message in the response body.

Does anyone know why this is not getting picked up in IE8?

**UPDATE**

Simplified version of our server-side code:

```
[OperationContract(), WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Images", Method = "POST")]
    public System.Guid CreateImage(System.IO.Stream Image)
    {

        //IE8 needs response to be in plain text format, or it will attempt to download the response :(
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        //perform validation
        BLL.Errors validationErrors = BLL.Utilities.ImageFileProcessing.ValidateSizeAndFormat(multipartRequestParser.FileContents);

        //if there were errors
        if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
        {
            //send back the errors
            throw new WebFaultException<BLL.Errors>(validationErrors, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        //save the image (returns the identifier for the image)
        System.Guid imageId = BLL.Custom.BeamUSBuyingWindow.DataTransferObjects.Brand.SaveImage(multipartRequestParser.FileContents);

        //set the response status and URI for created resource
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetStatusAsCreated(new System.Uri(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.BaseUri.AbsoluteUri + "/" + imageId.ToString()));

        return imageId;

    }
```

The method `ValidateSizeAndFormat` returns an array of `Errors` objects, which contain the error text I'm expecting. It's quite a big application.

I'm slightly perplexed that Chrome is picking up a 400 error in the jqXHR object and IE8 is picking up a 200 success. Despite similar Ajax error handling elsewhere, this issue is only happening with the File Upload plugin.

Comment: 400 you get from server side ... try to post code used in web service/asp.net

Comment: I've added some of my server side code. It's quite a big application :D

Comment: @SimonAdcock I'm having the same issue with v9.9.2 - did you ever figure out a fix?

Comment: @shrodes I'm afraid not. I had to implement a hack along the lines of `if (data.jqXHR.responseText) { /* assume failure */ }` which works in my case, but is not a great general solution.

Comment: My solution is to check `data.result`. If it's `undefined`, there's an error. But I still have no idea why `blueimp-file-upload` always detects status code as 200 even if there's a server error or a network error. It works fine on Chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my comment above, is not on server side.  I read carefully this page: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

I put here a sentence which opens my eyes and probably your eyes :)

`Do you get the error using more than one browser ?. If you have two or more Web browsers installed on your PC and the behaviour is not the same (one Web browser gives an HTTP 400 error visiting a site, another Web browser does not give the 400 error visiting the same site), then one of your browsers may be defective. Try to find an upgrade or security fix for the problem browser. If you recently changed some configuration options in the problem browser, try reversing the change to see if that helps.`

Please also read other points from that page.

Comment: Hi SnakeEyes, thanks for the link. My question may not be very clear. I'm actually expecting to see a 400 response, but instead I'm getting a 200 response in IE8. I want to see an error response, but the browser is somehow interpreting it as a success response. Upgrading the browser is sadly not an option as this is for a corporate client who don't want to upgrade from IE8. Many thanks for your help.